# Missing style error when adding a new textview component into the layout

Tags: android, textview, styles

I've searched for the articles that are discussing about the same topic,

but it accidentally seems like there aren't any.

I actually had the problem when setting the layout & edit the style xml file like below:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="NoTitleBarFulScn" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
     Customize your theme here.
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPreimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="ceolorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And then indicate the manifest file to use the `NoTitleBarFulScn` style:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/NoTitleBarFulScn"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Problem solved till here,

but the "Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?" error shows again when I was simply adding a new textview component...(It also shows an error about textview attributes missing below the missing style one.)

I tried also the sdk version setting & "invalidate caches / restart" option, but still doesn't work.

Also it seems like the new version of android studio has been set not to show the detail of the missing attributes it's saying, I still don't know where to find it.

Please give me some advice if possible,

thank you so much!

Comment: run the app and check whether its working fine or not. and as u mentioned that **accidentally this info is not available anywhere else** then probably you didnt check the google docs. it clearly explains that sometimes the views are rendered programatically and to save resources high level views are not rendered in preview window. at that time you get this error

Comment: @MohammedAtif

Thanks so much for replying, 

I ain't quite understand about what you are saying,

because that the textview is actually rendered in the preview,

but it shows the theme error of the layout?

And I want to solve it because it just keeps jumping out after every step I do, really annoying.

Comment: Is your app running properly? If you ignore the exceptions raised in preview?

Comment: @MohammedAtif Thanks so much for patiently replaying, I've found the solution that I think is the most likely cause in the very beginning, just simply add    
    <item name="android:textEditSuggestionItemLayout"></item>
    <item name="android:textEditSuggestionContainerLayout"></item>
    <item name="android:textEditSuggestionHighlightStyle"></item>
into the style definition of the XML file, because it occurs when I add a textview, so it must be the situation that the system can't find the corresponding textview attributes in current theme...

Comment: but I didn't know that the textview attributes should also be defined in theme style...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution that I think is the most likely cause in the very beginning,

just simply add 

`<item name="android:textEditSuggestionItemLayout"></item> 
<item name="android:textEditSuggestionContainerLayout"></item> 
<item name="android:textEditSuggestionHighlightStyle"></item>`

into the style definition of the XML file,

however it seems like the new version of android studio has been set not to show the detail of the missing attributes it's saying, I still don't know where to find it.